# How to delete keys in a nested dictionary of lists based on the values

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary, tree

I am working on a file representing a tree-like structure very similar to [flare.json](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1093025) which is known for D3.js community. What's the best way to delete all the leaves of the tree in python? In other words, I want to remove all the keys that don't have a 'children' key in their value.

example :

```
{
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "optimization",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
     ] ...
```

which should become:

```
{
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
    },
    {
     "name": "optimization",

     ] ...
```

In other words, I'm just cutting the leaves of the tree. In a children list is empty, it should be removed.

I tried this only to remove the keys and it did not work:

```
def deleteLeaves(pTree):
    if pTree.has_key('children'):
        for child in pTree['children']:
            deleteLeaves(child)
    else:
        del pTree
```

Comment: What should happen to the `children` keys that now reference to empty lists? In other words, what is the *expected output* here? Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Are you using any lib to serialize the json? Can you post the code you struggled with?

Comment: updated the question. I'm using python 2.7

Comment: But now you still have elements with `children` that don't have themselves have a `children` key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just edited the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28170339/667527) of @rchang to fix deletion of lists other than `children`.

```
def pruneLeaves(self,obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        isLeaf = True
        for key in obj.keys():
            if key=='children': 
                isLeaf = False
                if self.pruneLeaves(obj[key]): del obj[key]
        return isLeaf

    elif isinstance(obj, list) :
        leaves = []
        for (index, element) in enumerate(obj):
          if self.pruneLeaves(element): leaves.append(index)
        leaves.reverse()
        for index in leaves: obj.pop(index)
        return not bool(obj)
    else:  # String values look like attributes in your dict, so never prune them
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to approximate what you want:

```
def pruneLeaves(obj):

  if isinstance(obj, dict):
    isLeaf = True
    for key in obj.keys():
      if key == 'children': isLeaf = False
      if pruneLeaves(obj[key]): del obj[key]
    return isLeaf

  elif isinstance(obj, list):
    leaves = []
    for (index, element) in enumerate(obj):
      if pruneLeaves(element): leaves.append(index)
    leaves.reverse()
    for index in leaves: obj.pop(index)
    return not bool(obj)

  else:  # String values look like attributes in your dict, so never prune them
    return False
```

Tested with a truncated sample of your data:

```
data = {
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
  ]
}

pruneLeaves(data)
print data
```

And got these results:

```
{'name': 'flare', 'children': [{'name': 'analytics', 'children': [{'name': 'cluster'}, {'name': 'graph'}]}]}
```

Comment: the problem with this code is that it deletes other list values too. It should only delete empty 'children' items. I'll post the slightly modified version that doesn't delete other lists as an answer

Comment: @MostafaMV Fair enough - in your sample data, lists did not appear except as values correlating to "children" keys, so perhaps I inferred too much from that.

Comment: yeah you are absolutely right. Thanks for the initial code.